# What algorithms do you know for beltway reconstruction?

Tags: nt.number-theory, graph-theory, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

I've faced the beltway reconstruction problem and I've developed a simple backtrack algorithm, what algorithms do you know for this problem? 
**Beltway Reconstruction Problem**: 
Assume there is a set of non-identical integers between 0 and N, we only have pairwise distances of points of that set mod N, How can we reconstruct the original set using this?

Comment: [cross-posted](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/what-algorithms-do-you-know-for-beltway-reconstruction) on [cstheory.se].

Comment: See also the MO question [Difference Sets](http://mathoverflow.net/a/135471/6094), which also discusses the beltway reconstruction problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively recent result for a sparse case can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2386v1.pdf) (see Algorithm 2). It’s a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I've read these two papers: ___Reconstruction of Integers from Pairwise Distances___ & ___Reconstructing Sets From Interpoint Distances___. Any other references?