# Valid Difference Sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, computational-number-theory

Suppose

$$
P \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,N\},\quad |P| = K
$$

We calculate the differences as:

$$
d=p_i-p_j\mod N,\quad i\ne j
$$

Now let $a_d$ denote the number of occurrence of $d$ (for $d = 0, 1, 2, \dots , N −
1$), then we have a set

$$
D=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{N-1} \}
$$

Let's define a valid $D$ as a $D$ which is resulted from a points set $P$ (a $D$ which there exists some $P$ leading to it).

Reconstructing $P$ from $D$ is called [beltway reconstruction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=98598) and there are some algorithms for it, but I'm looking for some criteria that indicate the given $D$ is not a valid one.

One is $\sum_{d=1}^{N-1} a_d = K(K-1)$, i.e. if this equality doesn't hold for the given $D$ that $D$ is not a valid one.

The other is $a_i = a_{N-i}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,N-1$

**EDIT**:
consider these two sets of $D$'s ($a_0=K$ is included, too)

$(N,K) = (10,5)$:

$$\color{green}{\{5, 3,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     3\}}$$

$$\{5,2,     3,     2,     2,     2,     2,     2,     3,     2\}$$

$$\color{green}{\{5, 2,     2,     3,     2,     2,     2,     3,     2,     2\}}$$

$$\{5,2,     2,     2,     3,     2,     3,     2,     2,     2\}$$

$(N,K) = (11,8)$ :

$$\color{green}{ \{     8,     6   ,  6,     6   ,  5,     5   ,  5,     5   ,  6,     6   ,  6 \}}$$

$$\{     8 ,    6  ,   6 ,    5  ,   6 ,    5  ,   5 ,    6  ,   5 ,    6  ,   6\}$$

$$\{     8  ,   6 ,    6  ,   5 ,    5  ,   6 ,    6  ,   5 ,    5  ,   6 ,    6\}$$

$$\color{green}{\{     8   ,  6,     5   ,  6,     6   ,  5,     5   ,  6,     6   ,  5,     6 \}}$$

$$\{     8,    6     ,5,     6     ,5,     6     ,6,     5     ,6,     5     ,6\}$$

$$\color{green}{\{     8 ,    6    , 5 ,    5    , 6 ,    6    , 6 ,    6    , 5 ,    5    , 6 \}}$$

$$\{     8  ,   5   ,  6  ,   6   ,  6  ,   5   ,  5  ,   6   ,  6  ,   6   ,  5\}$$

$$\color{green}{\{     8   ,  5  ,   6   ,  6  ,   5   ,  6  ,   6   ,  5  ,   6   ,  6  ,   5 \}}$$

$$\color{green}{\{   8    , 5 ,    6    , 5 ,    6    , 6 ,    6    , 6 ,    5    , 6 ,    5 \}}$$

$$\{     8     ,5,     5     ,6,     6     ,6,     6     ,6,     6     ,5,     5\}$$

Only green ones are permissible and the others are not, while they satisfy symmetric criteria suggested thanks to Thomas. So there must be some asymmetric criteria.

**Are there any other criteria?**

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135464/difference-sets) is related, if helps.

Comment: There certainly must be other criteria, e.g., for $N=5$, $K=4$, there are many $D$ satisfying the two criteria given, but only one is valid.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for sharing your knowledge sincerely. Yes You are right, actually these are necessary conditions, and I'm looking for more necessary conditions.

Answer (score 3):

There are no doubt quite a few more necessary conditions; below are a couple of observations. I'm not sure how useful these are, without knowing your motivation.

(I will consider with $a_0$ also included, since this is always $K$, so we may assume that this condition is satisfied and convert the following conditions accordingly.)

$L_p$ bounds - as you point out, there is a forced $L_1$ bound:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n= K^2.$$

There is an obvious $L_\infty$ bound: $0\leq a_n\leq K$ for all $n$. Using the usual inequalities one may get similar bounds for all $L_p$ norms; for example,

$$ K^2\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n^2\leq K^3. $$

Perhaps more useful is the observation that $a_n$ must be a positive definite measure, that is, its Fourier coefficients are all real and positive, so:

$$ 0 \leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n e( mn/N ) \leq K^2 $$

for all $0\leq m < N$.

A good place to look is in the recent paper by Schoen and Shkredov, 'Higher moments of convolutions', which provides a host of useful results about $A\ast (-A)(n)$ (equivalent to your $a_n$).

Edit: more details. $a_n\geq 0$ because it counts the number of representations of $n$ as $p_1-p_2$ any count is non-negative. $a_n\leq K$ because otherwise by the pigeonhole principle there would be three distinct $p_1,p_2,p_3\in P$ such that $p_1-p_2=n=p_1-p_3$, a contradiction.

Expanding out $\sum a_n^2$ using the definition shows that it is the count of all quadruples $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\in P$ such that $p_1-p_2=p_3-p_4$ (this is often known as the additive energy of $P$). This is at least $K^2$ from the trivial quadruples with $p_1=p_3$ and $p_2=p_4$. It is at most $K^3$ because fixing any three of the quadruple uniquely determines the fourth.

Edit: an asymmetric criterion to handle the cases in the question. That is, in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ why is (again, including $n=0$ case here)
$$ (5,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3) $$
permissible but
$$ (5,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,2) $$
is not? We pass to the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. Since this has index 2 in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ we must be able to partition $P$ into two sets (the intersection with the two cosets) such that the difference from any two elements of the same set is in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, and the difference from any elements belonging to opposing sets is not. Hence looking at the $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ piece for each set:
$$ (5,2,2,2,2) $$
and 
$$ (5,3,2,2,3) $$
respectively, each must be the sum of two vectors which is 'permissible', now within $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

But this is ruled out by the $L_1$ necessary condition: the sum of all the components in the first is 13 = 4 + 9, so that's fine. But the sum of the all the components in the second is 15, which is not the sum of two squares. But the decomposition into two sets would give such a sum, a contradiction.

The same argument generalised gives the following criterion (a 'permissible' vector is a vector which arises from a difference set in that group):

> If a vector $v$ is permissible then for every subgroup $H\leq \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, if $v'$ denotes the restriction of $v$ to $H$, then $v'$ is the sum (as a vector) of $N/\lvert H\rvert$ many permissible (within $H$) vectors (not necessarily distinct). In particular, the sum of the components within $v'$ is the sum of $N/\lvert H\rvert$ squares.

Of course, this last point is not very useful when $N/\lvert H\rvert\geq 4$. But the other necessary conditions must also hold, so one of those could be used instead.

This is starting to feel like a necessary and sufficient condition, in a local to global kind of philosophy. Are there any examples when $N$ is prime that the 'symmetric' criteria don't rule out?

Comment: @Thomson Thanks for your contribution. How do you concluded that $0\leq a_n\leq K$, and $K\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n^2\leq K^3$ ?

Comment: I've explained in the edit (also corrected a typo - the lower bound for the $L_2$ bound should be $K^2$ not $K$).

Comment: Your contribution was great. Is there any criteria which are not symmetric over all $a_n$'s e.g. $\sum a_n$ or $\sum a_n^2$ , ... . Would you mind reading the EDIT part of the question? Thanks

Comment: Done; see edit.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? You need to look up what a 'coset' of a subgroup is. The index is just the number of cosets, or (by Lagrange's theorem) the size of the group divided by the size of the subgroup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9984/discussion-between-thomas-bloom-and-mahdi-khosravi)