# Embedding of Two Objects Into Higher Dimensions With Their Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, unitary-representations, isometries

Given two vector sets, $\vec x_i$ and $\vec y_i$ (for $i$=1,2,...N, but the dimensionality of each vector can be more than N), let their sum set be $\vec z_i = \vec x_i + \vec y_i$.  It's easy to compute the scalar inter-distances: $x_{ij} = \Vert{\vec x_i-\vec x_j}\Vert$, $y_{ij} = \Vert{\vec y_i-\vec y_j}\Vert$, $z_{ij} = \Vert{\vec z_i-\vec z_j}\Vert$.

But, what's the quickest computation method to go backwards (i.e., from all of the inter-distances to any "high-dimensional embedding")?  It seems I'm forced into ugly numerical "trial and error" methods even for small N=4 though there are easy analytical methods (for any N) if I didn't need to match the sum's inter-distances.

Comment: For a specific example, suppose there are 4 vectors in each set, so all 3 sets could be embedded individually as pyramids in our 3-D space.  But, if those 4 vectors each actually consist of 5 numbers, we probably need 4-D to simultaneously embed all 3 objects as a sum.

Comment: Presumably you meant: $y_{ij} = \Vert{\vec y_i-\vec y_j}\Vert$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y_i=0$ for all $i$.
Then $z_i = x_i$, $y_{ij}=0$, $z_{ij}=x_{ij}$,
and in this special case, your problem reduces to
reconstructing $x_i$ from the interpoint distances 
$x_{ij} = \Vert{\vec x_i-\vec x_j}\Vert$.
This is a known NP-hard problem, as discussed in earlier MO questions
("[Difference Sets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135464/6094)" and "[Feasibility of a list of prescribed distances in R^3](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7794/6094)").
So I think your problem cannot be easier than this intractible special case.

Comment: I agree.  Though the simpler problem is NP-hard, it's still analytically solvable.  This tougher problem, however, is forcing me into numerical solutions.