# a property implying co-circularity

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots, A_n$ be $n$ distinct points in the plane. 
For every $1\le i\le n$, let $D_i$ be the sum of the distances from point $A_i$ to all the other points.

Suppose that $D_i=D_j$ for every $1\le i< j \le n$.

Is it true that $A_1, A_2, \ldots A_n$ must be concyclic?

Comment: Not necessarily: this will hold for any shape with a transitive group of isometries, which includes for example non-square rectangles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not research level (and answered in the comments).

Comment: Note: the original question was put on hold. The comments above as well as @Joseph's answer are replying to the old question. The question was changed after a related question by the same user was answered (here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224037/metric-condition-forcing-convex-position). I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in general, a difficult problem, addressed in the paper below.
It goes under the phrase: the *beltway reconstruction problem*.

> Lemke, Paul, Steven S. Skiena, and Warren D. Smith. "Reconstructing sets from interpoint distances." *Discrete & Computational Geometry*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2003. 597-631.

There is some info in [an earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135471/6094).
Sets with nonunique reconstructions are called *homometric*. Here is a snippet from the above paper, addressing a property of regular polygons:

---

[image]

          

<sup>(From p.335 of conference version.)</sup>

---